# Which of the following is true among the given $4$ options?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

There is a unique function $f : (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ such as $\log(f(x))$ is convex and $$ a) \qquad \ f(1) = 1$$ $$ b) \quad f(x+1) = xf(x)$$ Options are

1. (a) is true
2. (b) is true
3. (a) and (b) both are true
4. None of the above

I am able to construct one example $e^{x-1}$, but this is not satisying (b). So what is the answer?

Comment: I think only (a) is correct

Comment: Doesn't (b) say that $f$ is periodic? Can a periodic function be convex?

Comment: (b) shows $f$ is periodic with $T=1$, So it can not be true unless $f$ be constant.

Comment: i am sorry. I have make some edits in function condition

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we only have condtion (a) alone. $f_1(x)=e^{x-1}$ and $f_2(x)=1$ both satisfy the condition.

Suppose we only have condition (b) alone. $f_1(x) = 1$ and $f_2(x)=2$ both satisfy the condition.

If we have both condition (a) and (b), from condition (b), we know that it must be a constant and from condition (a), the constant must be $1$.

Comment: Sir, so what's the answer according to you among the four options

Comment: third option, we need both conditions to have uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Only option (a) is true. Because if these conditions are true then these conditions will be true for every   f(x). So let us take example, $f(x)=x$. For this function only a) is true but b) is false.